# using the loop in custom meta is messing up 'add new' post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, admin, wpalchemy

When I use the following code in a ([wpalchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)) custom meta box, everything works fine.  That is until I pressed 'add new'.  At this point, the title, slug, featured image, etc.. are being pre-populated with the content from my 'products' post type.

The code builds a drop down within my 'case studies' post-type, and populates it with post titles/ids from my 'projects' post type.

How can I use the loop in the backend like this without messing stuff up.  I tried with `get_posts` as well as WP_Query.

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'projects', 'posts_per_page' => 200 );
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
  echo '<option value="' . get_the_id() . '"';
  echo '>' . get_the_title() . '</option>' . "\n";
endforeach;
```

**Edit: A little more background:**

I'm using the [wpalchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) class for custom meta boxes.  The following code is included in my functions.php file, after `/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php` https://github.com/farinspace/wpalchemy/blob/dev/wp-content/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php

```
$assoc_project = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array(
    'id' => '_assoc_project',
    'title' => 'Associated Project',
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/case-studies-assoc_proj-meta.php',
    'types'=> array('case-studies')
));
```

**Edit 2: Update**

I've tried and replicated this problem accross multiple browsers on my PC, but I just had a co-worker try on Ffox/mac and they don't have the problem.  I don't understand why this would be platform specific - but there it is...

Comment: what hook are you using to run that code?

Comment: @mrwweb not really sure, as I'm using the wpalchemy class.  I've updated my question with some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create a custom loop, you need to restore the global post variables with [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query).

Comment: I'm giving you the check, since this is the **right** answer.  I *was* using `wp_reset_query()` but somehow must've been doing something else wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I sorted this out myself.  Instead of `get_posts` or `WP_Query` I used a custom select query as [explained here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

My revised code:

```
<select name="<?php $mb->the_name(); ?>">
    <?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    $querystr = "
       SELECT $wpdb->posts.post_title,  $wpdb->posts.ID
       FROM $wpdb->posts
       WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'projects' 
       AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
       ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_name DESC
    ";
    $assocProjQuery = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
    foreach($assocProjQuery as $ap):
        echo '<option value="' . $ap->ID . '"';
            if ($mb->get_the_value() == $ap->ID ) echo $selected;
        echo '>' . $ap->post_title . '</option>' . "\n";
    endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
```